# Create associative array recursively in php -- "works" with echo

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, recursion, cakephp-2.x

I have a database with modules and submodules.

The function `getChildren()` is supposed to return the association between them to create a navigation element:

```
public function getChildren($id=0) {
        $modulesResult = $this->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('parent' => $id)
        ));
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($modulesResult as $key => $value) {
            echo "<li>";
            echo $value['module']['id'].". ".$value['module']['modulename'];
            $this->getChildren($value['module']['id']);
            echo "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
```

Which produces the following output:

```
1. Calendar
2. Mailbox
3. Statistics
     15. Local Statistics
     16. Regiona Sstatistics
     17. Global Statistics
     18. Custom Statistical Reports
4. Production
     19. Current Production
     22. Sort By Product
     23. Create Product
     24. List Products
     20. Production History
     25. From-To
     26. Yearly
     27. Monthly
     21. Projections
     28. Analysis
5. Trade
     29. E-store
     30. Products
     32. List Products
     33. Create Product
     34. Sort By Product
     31. Dashboard
```

*I want to do the same thing*, ***but instead of echo,*** **I want to put everything in an associative array.**

I tried this:

```
public function getChildrenTest($id=0, $array=array()) {
        pr($array);
        $modulesResult = $this->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('parent' => $id)
        ));
        foreach ($modulesResult as $key => $value) {
            #echo $value['module']['id'].$value['module']['modulename']."<br>";
            $array[$value['module']['parent']][$value['module']['id']] = $value['module']['modulename'];
            $this->getChildrenTest($value['module']['id'], $array);
        }
        return $array;
    }
```

But it outputs only the first level, like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Calendar
            [2] => Mailbox
            [3] => Statistics
            [4] => Production
            [5] => Trade
        )
)
```

I tried several variations of the code above but nothing works! Seems am stuck!

Am I losing some information on the recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public function getChildren($id=0) {
    $modulesResult = $this->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('parent' => $id)
    ));

    $array=[];
    foreach ($modulesResult as $key => $value) {

        $array[$value['module']['id']]=array(
            $value['module']['modulename']=>$this->getChildren($value['module']['id'])
        );
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Or you may as well use `find('threaded')`, which is the finder CakePHP provides to work with nested results:

```
$modulesResult = $this->find('threaded',['parent'=>'parent']);
```

Which equals to:

```
$modulesResult = $this->find('all');
$modulesResult = Hash::nest($modulesResult,['parentPath'=>'{n}.module.parent']);
```

See:

- [`Model::find('threaded')`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-threaded)
- [`Hash::nest()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::nest)

Comment: Thanks looks like what I want, I will try this and mark you as correct answer eventually :D

Comment: Found a better solution, the array you are creating is messy :), not sure if i should flag you correct though :D

Comment: The resulting array is messy because the approach is messy. We could add further 'post processing' to clean it up, but there are better ways of dealing with nested arrays. I've edited the answer to include `find('threaded')`. Feel free to accept whatever answer you feel is the best, it doesn't have to be mine :)

Comment: Thanks again :) I appreciate the effort and your time!